# How to use regexp to extract url links in img tags

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

```
<![CDATA[
<img referrerpolicy="no-referrer" src="https://scontent-sjc3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/3ae37927158eaae1bb9d4fe0752aa85f/5C1F0F58/t51.2885-15/e35/38261725_382280748969632_602638638102085632_n.jpg"><br>
]]>
```

just only want the `https://*.jpg`

Comment: In general, you should not use regex to parse HTML content.  The pattern `src="https?:\/\/[^"]+"` might work for what you are trying to do.

Comment: in which platform you are writing regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a JS regex then try:

```
/https:.*jpg/g
```

[Fiddle Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/wXIMo7/28)

Or another one as:

```
/https:+[\w\d-.\/]+jpg/g
```

[Fiddle Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/wXIMo7/29)

Or another without Greedy:

```
/https:.*?jpg/
```

[Fiddle Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/wXIMo7/30)

In both cases you will get output as:

```
https://scontent-sjc3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/3ae37927158eaae1bb9d4fe0752aa85f/5C1F0F58/t51.2885-15/e35/38261725_382280748969632_602638638102085632_n.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
https:[^\s]*?\.jpg
```

[^\s] = non spaces string

*? = non greedy

.jpg = must end with .jpg

it works for links like:

`https://scontent-sjc3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/3ae37927158eaae1bb9d4fe0752aa85f/5C1F0F58/t51.2885-15/e35/38261725_382280748969632_602638638102085632_n.jpg`

[Online regex tester](https://scontent-sjc3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/3ae37927158eaae1bb9d4fe0752aa85f/5C1F0F58/t51.2885-15/e35/38261725_382280748969632_602638638102085632_n.jpg)